# adx calculation to custom columns from a matrix rather than the default HLC

Tags: r, quantmod, adx

I have a matrix with stock prices and various other data. it is not the ordinary yahoo download therefore the titles for open, high, low and close are different.

I want to apply `adx <- adx(HLC(x),10)` however by default the adx function uses the HLC columns. How do i get to choose my own columns for the calculation? ie the name of column i want to use is (x$c,x$H and x$l)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't rename your columns to high, low and close, then you need to give them to the ADX function in this order (HLC), either as a data.frame or as a matrix.

an (bad but workable) example:

```
library(quantmod)
df1 <- data.frame(h = 1:100, l = 1:100, c = 1:100)
ADX(df1, 10)
       DIp DIn  DX ADX
  [1,]  NA  NA  NA  NA
  [2,]  NA  NA  NA  NA
  [3,]  NA  NA  NA  NA
  [4,]  NA  NA  NA  NA
  [5,]  NA  NA  NA  NA
  [6,]  NA  NA  NA  NA
  [7,]  NA  NA  NA  NA
  [8,]  NA  NA  NA  NA
  [9,]  NA  NA  NA  NA
 [10,]  NA  NA  NA  NA
 [11,] 100   0 100  NA
 [12,] 100   0 100  NA
 [13,] 100   0 100  NA
```